# How to determine whether a service was stopped in unit test?

Tags: java, android, robolectric

I'm unit testing a service using Robolectric. The service is meant to start, do some operations and then kill itself. I'm having trouble finding a way to assert that the service was stopped when he finished his job.

The code is fairly trivial, I have an instance of the service in my test case. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following method is what you are looking for:
http://robolectric.org/javadoc/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowService.html#isStoppedBySelf()